# Express Authentication Redirects Leading to Infinite Loop

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, infinite-loop, passport.js

I am attempting to set up a passport-local authentication on a node.js server using express. It seems like it should be very straight forward. But I am getting stuck.

these two snippets work fine together:

```
app.get('/', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
    res.redirect('/index.html', { user: req.user });
});

app.post('/login', 
    passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login.html', failureFlash: true, successFlash: "Success!" }),
    function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

The issue is there is nothing keeping me from typing "www.myurl.com/index.html" into the address bar and dropping right onto my page.

if I use a any code like this:

```
app.get('/index.html', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
    res.redirect('/index.html', { user: req.user });
});
```

It seems like i get caught in a loop... it would be nice if it could check my authentication and send me on my way, without eternally checking on each redirect. What is the method of avoiding this?

I noticed that the documentation seems to utilize .render, instead of redirect. But this SEEMS to require that I use .ejs and I would prefer not to do that. Is this a must?

**++For Reference++**

```
 function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
    res.redirect('/login.html')
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I'm guessing you're letting `express.static()` handle the requests for `index.html` and `login.html`? In that case, you could create a route for `index.html` that would first check authentication, and act accordingly:

```
app.get('/index.html', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {
  // if this block is reached, it means the user was authenticated;
  // pass the request along to the static middleware.
  next();
});
```

Make sure that the above route is declared *before* you add `express.static` to the middleware stack, otherwise it will get bypassed (Express middleware/routes are called in order of declaration, the first one that matches the request will get to handle it).

**EDIT:** I keep forgetting that this is possible, and much cleaner, too:

```
app.use('/index.html', ensureAuthenticated);
```

(instead of the `app.get` above)

Comment: I have ended up doing app.get('/index.html', ensureAuthenticated); and it is working fine so far. Would there be a reason to use "use" over "get"?

Comment: I tend to use `app.use` for 'real' middleware, like in my example code. Also, `app.use` will match request methods other than `GET`, but in this case that isn't really an issue. So apart from semantics, in this case there's no reason to pick one over the other :) (edit: there could also be potential side-effects from using `app.get` because it's handled by the router middleware, but I don't think they'll apply here either)

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using redirect on every route?All you need to do is

```
app.get('/',ensureAuthenticated,function(req,res){

// your route logic goes here

});
```

The ensureAutheticated will check whether your code is authenticated or not.Not need to redirect it every time through the login route.

[res.render](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.redirect) and [res.redirect()](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.render) are different things used for different purposes.

Redirect redirects to a route where as res.render()
 renders a view.The view can be any file [supported](http://jsdoc.info/visionmedia/consolidate.js/) by consolidate.js which is what you must be using if you are working with latest version of express.

So remove all those redirects from your routes and the infinite loop should cease.You only need to pass ensureAuthenticated to make sure the request are authenticated.